# Issues calculating probability (double integral)

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus

I'm giving the simultaneous density function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x,y)= \begin{cases}
\frac{4x^3}{y^3} & \text{if $0<x<1, x<y$}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Then I'm told to calculate $P(X+Y\leq1)$.
I've been struggling for couple of hours with the calculations, which I think is supposed to be:
\begin{equation*}
P(X+Y\leq 1)=\int_{0}^{1/2}\int_x^{1-x}\frac{4x^3}{y^3}\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation*}
But the problem here is that I get this:
\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{1/2}-\frac{2x^3}{(1-x)^2}+2x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation*}
and don't know how to continue since it gets worse for every partial integration I take.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
By the way I have to do it by hand, which is why it's difficult.

Comment: Hi. Sorry I actually made a typo, it's supposed to be $(1-x)^2$  and not $(1-x^2)$

Comment: That being said, $X+Y \le 1$ implies that we need to integrate over the region bounded by the lines $x=0$, $y=0$, and $y=1-x$.  This would be the integral $$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1-x} f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x.$$  It might be easier to Fubini this round and integrate with respect to $x$ first.

Comment: See that in some of that region value of the function is 0 the integral as OP writes it gives the same answer

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar Indeed, I misread the bounds in the definition of $f$ (thank goodness I left $f(x,y)$ as the integrand. :D).  Still, I think that integrating w.r.t. $x$ first will simplify matters.

Comment: Yes it solves the matter.

Comment: When solving this integral by computer I'm getting the answer $-\infty$ but I get $0.1589$ when solving for the integral I wrote, so I assume it's correct. I just don't know how that's done by hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the key here is hit the integral over the head with Fubini's theorem and integrate with respect to $x$, first.  Since a picture can be helpful:

[image]

It is a little tedious, but fairly straightforward:
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{1/2} \int_{x}^{1-x} f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&\quad= \color{blue}{\int_{0}^{1/2} \int_{0}^{y} f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y} + \color{orange}{\int_{1/2}^{1} \int_{0}^{1-y} f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y} \tag{by Fubini} \\
&\quad= \int_{0}^{1/2} \int_{0}^{y} \frac{4x^3}{y^3}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y + \int_{1/2}^{1} \int_{0}^{1-y} \frac{4x^3}{y^3}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y \\
&\quad= \int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{4}{y^3}\left( \frac{x^4}{4} \right]_{x=0}^{y}\,\mathrm{d}y + \int_{1/2}^{1} \frac{4}{y^3}\left( \frac{x^4}{4} \right]_{x=0}^{1-y}\,\mathrm{d}y \\
&\quad= \color{red}{\int_{0}^{1/2} y \,\mathrm{d}y} + \int_{1/2}^{1} \frac{(1-y)^4}{y^3}\,\mathrm{d}y \\
&\quad= \color{red}{\frac{1}{8}} + \int_{1/2}^{1} \frac{1 - 4y + 6y^2 - 4y^3 + y^4}{y^3} \,\mathrm{d}y \tag{binomial theorem} \\
&\quad= \frac{1}{8} + \int_{1/2}^{1} \left(y^{-3} - 4y^{-2} + 6y^{-1} + y\right)\,\mathrm{d}y \\
&\quad= \frac{1}{8} + \left( -\frac{2}{y^2} + \frac{12}{y} + 6\log(y)  + \frac{1}{2}y^2 \right]_{y=1/2}^{1} \\
&\quad= \frac{1}{8} + \left( -2 + 12 + 0 + 2\right) - \left( -\frac{2}{1/4} + \frac{12}{1/2} + 6\log\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \right) \\
&\quad= \color{violet}{\frac{1}{8}} + 12 - \left( 16 - 6\log(2) + \color{violet}{\frac{1}{8}} \right) \\
&\quad= (12-16) + 6\log(2) \\
&\quad= 6\log(2) - 4 \\
&\quad\approx 0.1589.
\end{align}

Comment: Very very impressive, how much time did this take :D

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar Given the time between my last comment and the publication of this answer: about an hour. :\

Comment: Wow, this is amazing. Very detailed and well written! It's amazing that someone would spend so much time and effort to help someone else out. I understand it thanks to you guys, so thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Integrate wrt to $x$ first. Use the following integration form

> $$\int_0^{1/2}\int_0^{y}\frac{4x^3}{y^3}dxdy+\int_{1/2}^1\int_0^{1-y}\frac{4x^3}{y^3}$$

Complete solution

> $$\int_0^{1/2}\int_0^{y}\frac{4x^3}{y^3}dxdy = \int_0^{1/2}\frac{1}{y^3}(y^4-0)dy=\frac{y^2}{2}\bigg|_0^{1/2}=\frac{1}{8}$$
>
> $$\int_{1/2}^1\int_0^{1-y}\frac{4x^3}{y^3}dxdy=\int_{1/2}^1\frac{(1-y)^4}{y^3}dy=\\ \int_{1/2}^1\frac{1-4y+6y^2-4y^3+y^4}{y^3}dy$$
>   And here is the answer [numerically](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20(1-y)%5E4%2Fy%5E3%20(0.5,1))

Comment: Hi. Do you mean
$\int_0^{1/2}\int_0^y \frac{4x^3}{y^3}dxdy+\int_{1/2}^{1}\int_0^1 \frac{4x^3}{y^3}dxdy$?

Comment: You are integrating over a region bounded by points $(0,0), (0,1), (0.5,0.5)$ so the first integral is the value for the lower half of the triangle and the second half is the value for the upper half of the triangle. In second integral you integrate till the $x=1-y$ line, if you use the integral you suggest it will include the area covered by points $(0,1), (0.5,0.5), (1, 0.5), (1,1)$ which is not what we are looking for.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. But why do you use y instead of $y^3$ in the fraction?

Comment: Oh thank you, I see.  Thank you so much for this very detailed response, it helps a lot!